# How can I install PostgreSQL 9 on RHEL 6?

Tags: linux, redhat, postgresql, rpm

I am new to RHEL 6 but have a project where I need a postgres 9 database and I only have RHEL 6 available to me. How can I safely do this? Should I install from source or is there a package around somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install open-source version of PostgreSQL you have three ways:

- Compile and install PostgreSQL from [source code](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v9.0.4/). Take a look at [Chapter 15](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/installation.html) if you need some details how to accomplish such install.
- Install PostgreSQL from postgresql90 packages as ewwhite pointed.
- Use [one-click installer](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload) provided by EnterpriseDB ([Installation Guide](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide)).

Note that if you are doing something serious, then you probably should use [latest minor version](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning) of PostgreSQL (at this time 9.0.4).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [official RPMs](http://www.pgrpms.org/) available directly from PostgreSQL at: http://www.pgrpms.org/

Find the [repo file](http://www.pgrpms.org/reporpms/repoview/letter_p.group.html) for your preferred distribution and install from there.

Also see: [PostgreSQL RPM Building Project - Yum Repository Howto](http://www.pgrpms.org/howtoyum.php)

Comment: Did you specifically want to compile from source? You mentioned Red Hat 6, so I thought you'd be interested in an RPM-based solution.